# How to bind C-` (backquote) in emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to bind `` C-` `` (control-backquote) but I could not do it.

The sexp

```
(global-set-key "\M-`" 'other-window)
```

works, whereas

```
(global-set-key "\C-`" 'other-window)
```

doesn't. It fails with the "Invalid modifier in string" error.

Comment: After a couple of tries, I manage it to work with (global-set-key [?\C-`] 'other-window), but I still want to know why

Comment: That's really weird. BTW-- It is fair to put you solution down as an answer. You are encouraged to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`"\C-a"` and similar do work because there is a ASCII code for them. There is none for C-`, simply use

```
(kbd "C-`")
```

By the way, this often more portable from one emacsen to another.

Comment: Thanks, Works, and seems clearer than that horrible question sign.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is fair to answer my own question:

```
(global-set-key [?\C-`] 'other-window)
```

But I don't know the meaning of that extra question mark.

Comment: The question mark means read the next bit as a character instead of something else (like a list or string or vector, etc.).